# Lost Short SF Story, Messages from Mars, uniquely shaped coil involved

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this in an anthology sometime in the 1970's.
A chap was winding various coils for his radio receiver.
He hears a message from 'Mars'?

The story ends when the 'special' coil is crushed by some accident.
The protagonist is concerned that he could never reproduce the 'unique' shape again!

I hope someone can help with this, it came up while discussing Inductance with a friend.

Comment: It sounds like a "before the golden age" story. Maybe from the 1920s or 30s. Can you remember if it had that feel to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Gerald Kersh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Kersh), [The Copper Dahlia](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?96968) (1949).

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is ["The Copper Dahlia"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?96968) by Gerald Kersh (published in Edmund Crispin's *Best SF Two* and elsewhere).

The device is wrecked when a cat jumps on it in pursuit of a mouse. But not before the hero receives horrifying news.

> The amoeboid Martians wish to render humans happy regardless of their condition. The hero sees that this will be a disaster, as a man burning to death will be happy and do nothing to save himself. A farmer will happily plough on till he hits a wall, and then be happy until he dies.

He ends by fleeing to a remote corner of the Gaspé Peninsula, and warning everyone to destroy any similar coils which they may find.